# Add "Insert citation" button to editor window

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, editing, markdown

Last year, MathOverflow has added a pretty nifty ["Insert citation" button](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2583/30516) to the markdown editor, which is very handy for inserting links to (mathematical) papers or books one wants to mention in their question or answer.

Would it be possible to have it activated at SciComp.SE as well, or is that something too specific for MO (which is still not 100% integrated into the SE network, as far as I know)?

Comment: Not sure; will have to ask the SE mod chat room.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry Any news on that?

Comment: Sorry, following up fell down my queue. I asked the mod chat room, and someone should be answering your question soon.

Comment: No worries, it *is* low priority. Thanks for following up!

Comment: @GeoffOxberry and Christian, please note we've [updated the feature](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3148/is-the-citation-helper-broken/3156#3156). Please let me know if anything is broken here.

Comment: @JonEricson Awesome, will do!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

MathOverflow is pretty well integrated at this point. I've enabled the fancier citation option on Computational Science:

[image: Fancy citations]

I notice the textbox overflows the popup. I'll check with a designer to see if we can get that fixed.

I also added the link for including citations in answers:

[image]

Notice something new? ;-)

Comment: I did :) Thank you very much, that's perfect!